# AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'warnings'

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, warnings

I want to try an example of LSTM online, but I meet some problems. This is my first time to use YAML.

I run the code including the parts below and these errors occur:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "lstm_test.py", line 112, in <module>
        lstm_predict(strings)
    File "lstm_test.py", line 74, in lstm_predict
        yaml.warnings({'YAMLLoadWarning': False})
AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'warnings'
```

I run the code on Windows 10, and I use Python 3.7.

```py
def lstm_predict(strings):

    print('loading model......')

    with open('../model/lstm.yml', 'r') as f:
        yaml_string = yaml.load(f)

    model = model_from_yaml(yaml_string)

    print('loading weights......')
    model.load_weights('../model/lstm.h5')
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

    for string in strings:
        line = Converter('zh-hant').convert(string.encode().decode('utf-8'))
        string0 = line.encode('utf-8')
        print("="*20)
        data=input_transform(string0)
        data.reshape(1,-1)

        #print data
        result=model.predict_classes(data)
        print(result) # [[1]]
        if result[0]==1:
           print(string,' positive')
        elif result[0]==0:
           print(string,' neural')
        else:
           print(string,' negative')
```

Actually, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'warnings'.
```

But, theoretically I think it should not raise any errors. What do I possibly miss?

Comment: You have a few misconceptions: `yaml.load()` doesn't return a string, so the variable name `yaml_string` is misleading and going to cause problems in maintenance. You have an error on line 74, but your code doesn't show that many lines: you should make a minimal piece of code, or at least shows us all the code that throws the error (and possible also the YAML that you are parsing). Finally the [recommended extension for YAML files](https://yaml.org/faq.html) has been `.yaml` since 2006. The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format is almost as old as YAML but something entirely different.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem as following picture 
[image]

It is okay now when I install PyYAML package like below command

```
     pipenv run pip install PyYAML --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

by the way, it is a different package between **pyyaml** and **PyYAML**

[image]

Comment: What did work for me tho is this pip3 install pyyaml --upgrade --ignore-installed

Comment: sorry @shivam13juna I have no idea about your issue , could you give me more information and what's wrong with you thanks

Comment: So the solution is to install a new package? How would installing 'PyYAML' have any effect on the problem with the 'pyyaml' package?

Comment: @rumble_shark sorry this issue happened a long time ago, I forgot what is going on with "pyyaml"